# Define a constraint for multiple type variables

Tags: haskell

In my codebase I have several types with a different number of type variables.

For example, consider

```
data MyType a b c = ...
data MyOtherType a b c d e = ...
```

Then I am defining functions using these types and I want to require that every type variable is an instance of `Show`.

To avoid too much repetition I used `ConstraintKinds` to define types

```
type Show2 a b = (Show a, Show b)
type Show3 a b c = (Show2 a b, Show c)
type Show4 a b c d = (Show3 a b c, Show d)
type Show5 a b c d e = (Show4 a b c d, Show e)
```

so that in the definition of my functions I can use

```
f :: (Show5 a b c d e) => MyOtherType a b c d e -> ...
```

Now my question is: is there a way to simplify the definition of types `Show2`, ..., `Show5`? It looks like their definition is recursive and I was wondering if there was an extension which allowed me to define them in one go

Comment: FWIW, `Data.Functor.Classes` defines `Show1` and `Show2` classes. They're different than the types shown here, but perhaps those standard classes could serve as inspiration...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use a type family, and type-level lists-of-types.

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies, DataKinds, TypeOperators #-}

import Data.Kind

type family ShowN (xs :: [*]) :: Constraint
type instance ShowN '[] = ()
type instance ShowN (t ': ts) = (Show t, ShowN ts)

foo :: ShowN '[a, b, c] => a -> b -> c -> String
foo xa xb xc = show xa ++ " " ++ show xb ++ " " ++ show xc

main :: IO ()
main = putStrLn (foo 3 True 'f')
```