# How to package a state machine library

Tags: haskell

I want to use Haskell for finite state machine analysis and documentation. I want the library to be generic enough to require little boilerplate when I instantiate a particular FSM.

A state machine definition is based on states `s`, events `e`, and actions `a`. Primary requirements are:

- Display the machine as text (define or derive `Show`).
- Display in fancy form, such as emitting `dot` notation for Graphviz.
- Determine correctness (for some definition of correctness), termination conditions and other properties of a directed graph.
- Use the state machine definition to aid in ensuring test coverage for implementations of the FSM in other languages (source code generation, test coverage analysis).

My initial implementation looked like:

```
import Data.List

data StateMachine s e a =
    StateMachine { 
                   states :: [s]                    -- ^states that the machine can be in
                 , events :: [e]                    -- ^events that the machine can process
                 , actions :: [a]                   -- ^actions the machine can perform
                 , initialStates :: [s]             -- ^starting states
                 , transitions :: [((s,e),(a,s))]   -- ^state transitions
                 }

-- |Find the action and next state for an event in the given state
nextOperation :: (Ord s, Ord e, Eq a) => 
                 StateMachine s e a -> s -> e -> Maybe (a, s)
nextOperation sm st ev = lookup (st, ev) (transitions sm)

-- |Find the next state from this state for an event, if present
nextTransition :: (Ord s, Ord e, Eq a) => StateMachine s e a -> s -> e -> Maybe s
nextTransition sm st ev = fmap snd $ nextOperation sm st ev
allNextStates :: (Ord s, Ord e, Eq a) => StateMachine s e a -> s -> [e] -> [s]
allNextStates _ _ [] = []
allNextStates sm st (ev:es) = case nextTransition sm st ev of
                                Just st' -> st': allNextStates sm st es
                                Nothing  -> allNextStates sm st es

-- |Compute the set of states reachable from a state
reachableStates :: (Ord s, Ord e, Eq a) => StateMachine s e a -> s -> [s]
reachableStates sm st = nub $ allNextStates sm st (events sm)

-- |Compute the transitive closure from the initial states
transitiveClosure :: (Ord s, Ord e, Eq a) => StateMachine s e a -> [s]
transitiveClosure sm = transitives sm (initialStates sm) (initialStates sm)
    where
        transitives :: (Ord s, Ord e, Eq a) => StateMachine s e a -> [s] -> [s] -> [s]
        transitives _ [] reach = reach
        transitives stm reachable@(st: sts) reach =
             let r = reachableStates stm st
                 rs = [r' | r' <- r, not (r' `elem` reach)]
             in
                if null rs
                then transitives stm sts reach
                else transitives stm (sts ++ rs) (reach ++ rs)
```

From there, almost all of the operations needed to test reachability, and transitive closures could be readily built. However, I ended up with `(Ord s, Ord e, Eq a)` constraints everywhere, and kept running into "ambiguous type" problems. This also irritates the heck out of me, as I could readily define this using an abstract class in Java, let's say.

My second approach was to use type families, but this has not gone well. The first step was the definition of the class:

```
{-# language TypeFamilies #-}
{-# language MultiParamTypeClasses #-}

...    

class (Ord s, Show s) => SMstate s
class (Ord e, Show e) => SMevent e
class (Eq a, Show a) => SMaction a

class (SMstate s, SMevent e, SMaction a) => MachineState s e a where
    data MS s e a
    allEvents      :: MS s e a -> [e]
    initialStates  :: MS s e a -> [s]
    allStates      :: MS s e a -> [s]
    allActions     :: MS s e a -> [a]
    nextOperation  :: MS s e a -> s -> e -> Maybe (a,s)
nextTransition :: MS s e a -> s -> e -> Maybe s
nextTransition sm st ev = fmap snd $ nextOperation sm st ev
nextState      :: MS s e a -> s -> e -> s
nextState sm st ev = case nextTransition sm st ev of
                        Just st' -> st'
                        Nothing  -> st
allNextStates  :: MS s e a -> s -> [e] -> [s]
allNextStates _ _ [] = []
allNextStates sm st (ev:evs) =
    let nextStates = allNextStates sm st evs
    in  (maybeToList $ nextTransition sm st ev) ++ nextStates
reachableStates :: MS s e a -> s -> [s]
reachableStates sm s = nub $ allNextStates sm s (allEvents sm)
transitiveClosure :: MS s e a -> [s]
transitiveClosure sm = transitivesOf sm (initialStates sm) (initialStates sm)
    where
        transitivesOf :: MachineState s e a => MS s e a -> [s] -> [s] -> [s]
        transitivesOf _ [] reach = reach
        transitivesOf sm reachable@(st:sts) reach =
            let r = reachableStates sm st
                rs = [r' | r' <- r, r' `notElem` reach]
            in
                if null rs
                then transitivesOf sm sts reach
                else transitivesOf sm (sts ++ rs) (reach ++ rs)
```

Because the class constraints are wired into the definitions around `MachineState`, I no longer have to worry about propagating the constraints.

Are type families the way to go with this? How do I connect the `StateMachine` to the `MachineState` class?

Comment: What's wrong with `(Ord s, Ord e, Eq a)` constraints everywhere? To me seeing that in a type signature tells me a lot of things I probably want to know anyway about the value. You can abbreviate it with e.g. `type Machine s e a = (Ord s, Ord e, Eq a)` if you just don't like typing it repeatedly.

Comment: If you have a function that needs only the state `s`, and it does so by invoking `nextOperation`, you have to supply the three constraints. GHC won't compile such a function because it doesn't use `e` or `a`, and now you have to do backflips to get it to compile.

Comment: Your statement is true, but only vacuously: if you have a function that invokes `nextOperation`, then it is not true that it needs only the state `s`. So the premise of your "if" is false. To me this sounds like an XY problem. Why don't you put the details of the problem you're *actually* having instead of this vague surrogate? Show us the code for the thing you're actually having trouble with.

Comment: A [recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53114614/1126841) might be relevant.

Comment: It's not vacuous when it takes substantial time to decode error messages, sort through which language extensions I should and shouldn't use, etc. I edited my question with more code to show the difference in expressiveness using type family approach.

Comment: Your code as posted compiles fine here. If you want help with a problem, you need to show what doesn't work (that you wish *would* work) together with the error you get.

Comment: I've thought of designing state machine by the past I came up with the fact that  a function along `State -> ev -> Maybe (State, [a])`  should be enough. No need for typeclass or type or anything. Am I wrong ?

Comment: It compiles fine now. I still have a requirement to show the results of the `transitiveClosure` function. That requires adding `Show` constraints to **every** ... **single** ... **function**. I have two more constraints waiting in the wings. Using the type family approach allows specifying the constraints in one place instead of dozens of places, most of which have no use for the constraint. We call this "tramp typing", analogous to "tramp data".

Comment: @BobDalgleish No, you don't need to add `Show` to every single function. Only to those functions which show the results of `transitiveClosure`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That data family doesn't really accomplish anything your concrete parameterised `StateMachine` doesn't. The only real difference is that the constraints are packed into a single constraint, as the “superclasses” of `MachineState`. But that doesn't require the data family – you could as well use

```
class (SMstate s, SMevent e, SMaction a) => MachineState s e a
 {- Empty! -}

data StateMachine s e a =
    StateMachine { states :: [s]
                 , ... }
```

In fact you don't even need a class for this at all:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ConstraintKinds #-}
type MachineState s e a = (Ord s, Show s, Ord e, Show e, Eq a, Show a)
```

...though I would dispute that it's a good idea to *always require `Show`*.

So, no, I'd say a data family is not the way to go. Your original approach is the way to go, just listing whatever constraints each function actually needs.

If you're running into ambiguous types, that probably means just you've accidentally mentioned a type variable in a function that does *not* use a full `StateMachine` but merely some e.g. list of actions. In that case, it should normally be enough to just remove the constraint.

There are some applications where ambiguous types actually are useful. I don't think this should be the case for yours, but you can check out the `-XTypeApplications` extension, which is what's needed to invoke functions with ambiguous type.

---

A a general workflow, I recommend this:

1. Start your functions with a signature, but *without any constraint* and with empty implementation.

   ```
   nextOperation :: StateMachine s e a -> s -> e -> Maybe (a, s)
   nextOperation = _
   ```
2. Let GHC's typed-hole feature help you writing the implementation.
3. Add any constraints the compiler wants.

If it also complains about missing *extensions*, here are the ones I would always do without qualms:

- `FlexibleInstances` (includes `TypeSynonymInstances`)
- `FlexibleContexts`
- `TypeFamilies`
- `GADTs`
- `ConstraintKinds`

Not uncontroversial, but IMO also no big deal are

- `UndecidableInstances`
- `LiberalTypeSynonyms`
- `AllowAmbiguousTypes`+`TypeApplications`
- `Rank2Types`

Don't use, unless you really want to

- `OverlappingInstances` (resp. the `Overlapping`/`Overlappable` pragmas)
- Definitely not `IncoherentInstances`
- `ImpredicativeTypes`

Comment: `ConstraintKinds` is deprecated. If you don't pass the`Show` constraints into each function, the result won't be `Show`able.

Comment: @BobDalgleish no, constraint kinds are not deprecated. I think you're confusing them with data declaration constraints, which are something different.

Comment: Thank you for the complete answer. Not only did you provide technical details, but you helped me in thinking about the problem I am trying to solve.

Answer (score 0):

I needed a few state machines by the past and AFAIR everything boilds down to just one transition function and the use of a few basic typeclass.
Your `nextOperation` function should be enough

For example, let's say I have

```
type Transition s e a :: s -> e -> Maybe (a,s)

data State = Pending | InProgress | Processed 
data Even = Start | Finished

nextOperation :: Transition State Event (IO ())
nextOperation Pending Start = Just (print "started", InProgress)
nextOperation InProgress Finished = Just (print "finished", Processed)
nextOperation _ _ = Nothing
```

You can create a function which given a list of transitions create a `nextOperation` like function

```
fromTransition :: [(s, e), (a,s)] -> s -> e -> Maybe (a,s)
```

(I let you implement it)

To write the `transitiveClosure` function you'll need the list of all states, all events and all initial states. Getting all states and all events can be done easily by using `[minBound .. maxBound]`, this requires the `Enum` and `Bounded` constraints which are generated automatically from GHC, so you just need

```
data State = Pending | InProgress | Processed deriving (Eq, Show, Enum, Bounded)
```

For the initial state, you have two options, you can either pass it as an argument to transitiveClosure or create a new typeclass

```
class Initials a where
     initials :: [a]
```

With a few common instances

instance Initials () where initials = [()]
   instance Initials (Maybe a) where initials = [Nothing]
   instance Initials Bool where initials = [False]
   instance Num a => Initials a where initials = [0]

Things starts to be interesting with things like tuple

```
instance (Initials a, Initials b) => Initials (a,b) 
     where initials = liftA2 (,) initials initials
```

And of course `State`

```
instance Initials State where initials = [Pending]
```

Then `transitiveClosure` just need the following signature

```
transitiveClosure :: ( Bounded s, Enum s, Initials s
                     , Bounded e, Enum )
                  => (Transition s e a) -> [s]
```

We created only one typeclass (`Initials`) which has (pretty much) nothing todo with a state machine can be reused for something else. Moreover, via the `(,)` instance, you can easily extend your state and have for free you new initials states.

Everything else is just functions, which manipulate or create `Transition`s (I'use a type synonym here, but you could just use the plain function type). Some function might more contrains that other (ex, Show or Ord, Enum, etc ...) but that's the beauty of it.

TL;DR
In short, a state machine is just a transition function `s -> e -> Maybe (a,s)`. Haskell if a functional language, so we can actually modelize it just as a function. Nothing more